# Why nvidiabl module is not working in precise?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, vaio

I've just installed nvidiabl module from https://github.com/downloads/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/nvidiabl-dkms_0.74_all.deb and screen brightness still is not changing.
I have NVIDIA G210M, Precise amd64, VAIO VPCCW19FX

Answer (score 1):

Now working.

1-Downloaded nvidiabl debian base distributed version >> https://github.com/downloads/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/nvidiabl-dkms_0.74_all.deb

2- Installed it dpkg -i nvidiabl-dkms_0.74_all.deb

3- Add module to /etc/modules

4- Download oBacklight Script >> http://dev.osource.se/files/oBacklight_0.3.8.tar.gz (version 039 have an sh error try avoid it till is repaired).

5- Untar it tar -xvf oBacklight_0.3.8.tar.gz

6- cd to the untared directory

7-Give the script execution permission chmod +x oBacklight( I also change the owner and group to root but thats because im a little paranoid. You can avoid this.)

8-Copy oBacklight script to the /etc/init.d directory

9-Add it to the start up update-rc oBacklight defaults

NOTE: Depending on your laptop model, you may have to change the script mode. See >> http://dev.osource.se/docs/obacklight/

Ok now you're ready. In case you dont want to reboot now, just 'modprobe nvidiabl' and '/etc/init.d/oBacklight start' and test yourself.