# Compiz not working and Compiz Options in Fusion Icon are greyed out

Tags: compiz

I'm having trouble with Compiz, since I upgraded to 12.04. I have an nvidia-card (GeForce 9600M GT). In general Compiz works, but it has performance issues and rendering problems as in the following screenshot 1, that make usage impossible.

[image]

According to my research, the loose-binding option could help solving the problem. Unfortunately this is unavailable to me, as the Compiz Options in the Fusion Icon are greyed out.

[image]

Additionally the command-line argument `--loose-binding` for Compiz provokes an error that this option is unavailable. Same goes for the `--indirect-binding` option.

How to make those options available or solve the rendering problems in general?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix most nvidia errors

Open a terminal and add the nvidia PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Then update the repos

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally update the drivers

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now reboot, and when you log back in you will have a working, up to date nvidia driver in Ubuntu ;)

You could then reinstall compiz with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz
```

Good luck

Comment: I tried both of this out and my nvidia drivers are now updated to version 304.43. Unfortunately it did not change anything regarding the compiz issue. Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Nvidia drivers are not working, or not installed. As a result there is no extended graphic support and no graphic bells and whistles, meaning Compiz and Fusion cannot work.

In some versions of the Nvidia drivers there was/is a bug and due to a missing header file, the driver is not installed properly, and not working.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

then reboot and check Compiz (when I had a similar problem, the removal solved the problem). if no change, reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

then reboot and check Compiz again. If still no luck, maybe one of the following links can help:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/993506

https://askubuntu.com/questions/150601/why-nvidiabl-module-is-not-working-in-precise

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did this after updating the drivers as advised in the other suggestion. It did not solve the problem. I don't have the impression the drivers are not working, because apart from compiz the fancy opengl stuff works perfectly fine (e.g. glxgears or the game Psychonauts). Still, thank you for helping.